# Scope of Variable and object creation

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

for the below code from the online c++ quiz section
http://www.interqiew.com/ask?ta=tqcpp02&qn=3 - I am unable to figure out the answer - I have added the print statement -

here is what I understand

Step A - Object B creation starts with Constructor of B for parameter m_x - we reach base Class A 
       -- step 1 executed output 0  - and increments m_i to 1

Step B - Code now becomes m_x(2)
       -- step 1 executed output 2   and increments m_i to 3
creation of m_x done

Step C - Code Reaches A[2]  ( so for two objects below would happen)
        -- step 1 executed output 0  and increments m_i to 1
creation of A[0] and A[1] done

I am visualizing object b with 3 containers m_x , A[0] and A[1] each with value of m_i

I dont understand below output - how do we get output 2 - which value of m_i is used ?

Step D - enters the step3 region
        -- step 3 executed output 2

Output -

step 1 --- 0
1
step 1 --- 2
3
step 1 --- 0
1
step 1 --- 0
1
step 3 ----2

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int n = 0)
        : m_i(n)
    {
        std::cout << "step 1 --- " << m_i << endl;
        ++m_i;
        std::cout <<  m_i << endl;
    }

protected:
    int m_i;
};

class B
    : public A
{
public:
    B(int n = 5) : m_a(new A[2]), m_x(++m_i)
    { 
      std::cout << "step 3 ----" << m_i << endl; 
    }

   ~B() { delete [] m_a; }

private:
    A m_x;
    A *m_a;
};

int main()
{
    B b;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should that be step-1 etc? BTW - You are forgetting inheritance whereby the base needs to be constructed first

Comment: `B` constructor starts by constructing its base class `A`, then proceeds to construct its members, in the order they appear in the class definition - `m_x` first, then `m_a`. Two more instances of `A` are constructed in the initializer of `m_a`. Finally, the body of `B` constructor is executed.

Comment: Ah so u mean - it would be something like below   Step 0 - Constructor for b - reaches base class - executes step -1  i.e. 0 and increments it to value 1 --  now m_x is created incremented to 2 out put to 2 and so on ..                    
I think I got it now ..!!! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main you are constructing a B

But B inherits an A

So do that first. So `m_i` gets initialised and `std::cout << "step 1 --- " << m_i << endl;` is executed.

Processing continues for the B constructor.

Then `m_x` followed by `m_a` will be initialised - not the compiler rearrange things here!

For `m_x` the `A` contructor is called twice from the new operator. Followed by once for the `m_a` - i.e. 3 x ``std::cout << "step 1 --- " << m_i << endl;` is executed.

Then follows the rest of the constructor i.e. `td::cout << "step 3 ----" << m_i << endl;` is executed. What happens to Step 2 is a mystery.

Comment: Ok I think I got it  -  the big container i.e. object b has its own value of m_i - thanks for the explaination

Comment: There are four instances of `A` being created by this program, and so four independent copies of `m_i`. Namely, `b.A::m_i`; `b.m_x.m_i`; `b.m_a[0].m_i`; and `b.m_a[1].m_i` - constructed in that order.